# Creat new project from GitExtensions clone

Tags: git, github, git-extensions

I've been using GitExtensions with Visual Studio. However I've just realised it has only been tracking the project sub-directory - and not the project file itself.

Now when I come to clone the repository, I cannot open the project - its just the individual files (eg. forms, classes, etc).

So I thought I'd clone it into a sub folder just the same and just copy the project file across myself... But when I clone the tracked files, GE puts it all inside ANOTHER directory with the same name as the REMOTE repository - which is not the project name - so of course the project file won't work because it has the wrong paths...GAH!

How can I either get GE to start tracking the original project file in the parent directory, or make it put the CONTENTS of the repository in the new directory that I want with the name I choose?

Just about ready to delete the entire setup, remote and locals, and start from scratch without GE!!

Comment: Have you tried, after GitExtensions places the cloned folder inside the wrong place, just moving that folder inside the project folder and renaming it to have the correct name?

Comment: Then that breaks the repository as GE then has the wrong paths. Think I may finally have it sorted anyway, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I posted this Q after nearly a day of banging my head of the wall and shortly after posting found "an" answer, mostly out of the process of elimination.

In GitExtensions I opened the GitBash and navigated to the project's parent directory - which holds the project file. Then I ran the following command the clone the project *into* a directory of the name I wanted and that matched what the project file was expecting:

```
$ git clone https://www.github.com/myUserName/myRepositoryName theNeededDirectoryName
```

Now the contents of the repository are in the directory `theNeededDirectoryName` which is the sub-directory I required.

The project file has opened OK, will build, commit and push. BUT opening the solution in visual studio will no longer allow me to "start" debugging - only "attach" - dont know what this is but the OP is answered

Comment: The attach/start prolem was resolved by simply closing the project then visual studio then opening again by clicking on the project file. Finally... though I guess the project file is still not indexed...

Comment: `git clone` is what I was going to suggest before you answered this yourself. It is the right way to do it.